# Two buttons and webView between them

Tags: java, android, webview

How is the best way to add in layout two buttons (on top and on bottom) and webView between them?

I try:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/first"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="First" />

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="350dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/first"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/last"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/webView"
        android:text="Last" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

But this show me only first button and WebView. Maybe for height is better way than 350dp?

How can I make it?

Comment: Why don't you use weights?

Comment: @Eenvincible how? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this using weights; always avoid setting physical values in your views.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

   <Button
      android:id="@+id/first"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="0dp"
      android:layout_weight="0.2"
      android:text="First" />

   <WebView
      android:id="@+id/webView"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="0dp"
      android:layout_weight="0.6"
      android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal />

  <Button
      android:id="@+id/last"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="0dp"
      android:layout_weight="0.2"
      android:text="Last" />

</LinearLayout>
```

That will do what you want; i.e place the button1 on top and button2 at the bottom and the web view in the middle; the weights help share the screen accordingly without hardcoding values like heights.

I hope this helps.